# How to search for the latest video of a certain duration from a particular YouTube channel

Tags: youtube, search

I watch documentaries regularly and usually visit Vice and BBC News channels in YouTube. I always look for the latest documentaries/news with a duration of more than 20 minutes. My question is: how can I search within a particular YouTube channel (e.g.: BBC News) for the latest uploaded video with a duration greater than 20 minutes?

I have tried the following query but the results are not relevant:

```
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_sort=video_date_uploaded&filters=long&search_query=bbc+news
```